# Pass parameter from command line in python

Tags: python

I have a simple task and want to run command from the line.
E.g.

```
python3 -c 'print(2*2)'
```

The issue is when I want to invoke a function and pass parameter to it. E.g I want to lower the string 'ABC'.
I use

```
python3 -c 'print(x="ABC",x.lower())'
```

Hence my question: how could I pass string value to function when invoke python from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html#sys.argv) to obtain command-line arguments:

```
$ python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.argv[1].lower())" HELLO
hello
$
```